# How to stop Android Studio indexing parent folder of multiple subdirectories

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, cmake

I have an Android Studio Project that builds a native activity with C++, Gradle and CMake. The android project lives here `src/myproject/myandroidproject`.

The project lives in a large repository, that also contains a large folder (~50GB), `src/thirdparty`, full of thirdparty libraries.

The android project uses CMake and includes libraries from the `src/thirdparty` folder with `add_subdirectory`: `add_subdirectory(../../thirdparty/mylibrary)`.

There's 5 total libraries that are used in the android project. I'm running into an issue when importing all of these with `add_subdirectory` that Android Studio will begin indexing the whole `src/thirdparty` folder, instead of each individual library folder. This causes Android Studio to completely freeze trying to index this massive folder.

I've noticed that if I only import up to 2 libraries from `src/thirdparty` that Android Studio indexes each individual library folder, and not the whole `src/thirdparty` folder. This is what I would like Android Studio to be indexing. However, when I try to include more than 2 libraries, Android Studio will then switch to trying to index the whole of `src/thirdparty`. I do not want this as it causes Android Studio to freeze.

I know that I can right click the `src/thirdparty` folder in Android Studio and mark the directory as excluded, but this seems like it needs to be done on every gradle sync, which is undesirable. I'm looking for a way to not  have to do this every time I sync the project.

I have tried to use the gradle idea plugin, but am getting stuck working out how to try to exclude folders in a different directory tree than the one that the project is in.

Is there any way to get Android Studio to index each individual project instead of the whole `src/thirdparty` folder?

Comment: Does it help if you use the gradle idea plugin to use `excludeDirs += file('src/thirdparty')` to exclude the whole thirdparty folder? Or use a groovy code with a loop to use `excludeDirs += file(xxx)` to exclude each subfolder one by one?

Comment: @LJreplica I can't seem to work out how to exclude dirs in a different directory tree, i've tried `excludeDirs += file('../../src/thirdparty')`, but doesn't seem to help unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the real location of the other projects caused Android Studio to also index the sibiling directories when I was referencing more than 2 projects in the same directory.

I instead switch to symlink-ing to the project locations from within my own project directory, which caused Android Studio to only index the projects I was trying to include.